# How can I avoid URL encoding when clicking on links in iTerm2?

Tags: iterm

In iTerm2, if I output this from a zsh script:

`echo "https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query;query=..."`

The output will look right:

`https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query;query=...`

If I copy and paste that URL into the browser, it will work. But if I command-click the link, It will go into the browser like this:

`https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query%3Bquery%3D...`

GCP will not understand it. How can I get iTerm2 to not urlencode the URL? And is there a good reason it does that?